# https deployment with capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, bitbucket, capistrano, capistrano3

I'm trying to deploy a rails app on a local server with capistrano. 
However, the server is unable to ssh to the outside(internet), so i am unable to use `git@bitbucket.org:sample/repo.git` as repo url in deploy file. Instead I use `https://user@bitbucket.org:sample/repo.git`. But when i run `cap production deploy` I get an invalid username or password error.
Below is my deploy.rb file

```
lock "3.8.1"

set :scm, :git
set :application, "sample"
set :scm_username, "user"
set :scm_password, "password"
set :repo_url, "https://user@bitbucket.org:sample/repo.git"

set :branch, "production"

set :deploy_to, "/home/deploy/sample"
```

Can i make it such that cap asks me for password (if it doesn't use the `scm_password` field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```
set :scm_username, "user"
set :scm_password, "password"
```

to

```
set :git_http_username, "user"
set :git_http_password, "password"
```

Also, I think you can just put the username/password in the URL, e.g.:

```
set :repo_url, "https://user:password@bitbucket.org:sample/repo.git"
```